# Getting 2nd Next Value in For Loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop

So, expansion onto an earlier question I had. I made some changes to my code which caused me to have to rethink how to tackle the problem.

To reiterate, I have a list of bank transactions like this:

```
[08.10.17,D,520,08.11.01,W,20]
```

Each "transaction" is in pairs of three, where the first is the date, second is the type (W or D) and third is amount.

What I need to do is calculate the balance.

I imagine the pseudo-code would look something like this

```
for i in list:
    if i == 'D':
        bal = bal + (i+1)
    if i == 'W':
        bal = bal - (i+1)
```

So essentially, I want to just loop through the list, when it finds one of the transaction types, the next number would be the amount to add/subtract.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Have you read the answers to your last question? If you have read them, and still need to ask this question, you haven't even understood the answers to your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = ['08.10.17','D','520','08.11.01','W','20']
for date, type, amount in zip(data[0::3], data[1::3], data[2::3]):
    print date, type, amount
```

This would output:

```
08.10.17 D 520
08.11.01 W 20
```

You could also do the following, which has better performance:

```
def convert(stuff):
    it = iter(stuff)
    return zip(it, it, it)

for date, type, amount in convert(data):
    print date, type, amount
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not beholden to that odd list structure, I'd suggest a different approach:

**list of tuples**

```
mylist = [('08.10.17','D',520),('08.11.01','W',20)]
bal = 0

for transaction in mylist:
    if transaction[1] == 'D':
        bal = bal + transaction[2]
    elif transaction[1] == 'W':
        bal = bal - transaction[2]
```

As @sharth said above, you could get this list structure from your original list structure:

```
data = ['08.10.17','D',520,'08.11.01','W',20]
mylist = zip(data[0::3], data[1::3], data[2::3])
# returns: [('08.10.17', 'D', 520), ('08.11.01', 'W', 20)]
```

**arrays**

However, you can avoid for-loops altogether for this problem by using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

data = ['08.10.17','D',520,'08.11.01','W',20]
mylist = zip(data[0::3], data[1::3], data[2::3])

initial_balance = 0 # our initial balance

myarr = np.array(mylist) # generate an array based on our list

# create an array of the amounts with the appropriate sign; negative if 
# it is a withdraw, positive if a deposit
amounts = np.zeros(len(myarr)) 
amounts[:] = myarr[:,2] # grab the withdrawal/deposit amounts

signs = np.ones(len(myarr)) # an array of 1s (one for each transaction)
signs[np.where(myarr[:,1]=='W')] = -1 # make all the withdraws = -1 

amounts *= signs # multiply the amounts by appropriate signs

# our balance is now just our initial balance plus the sum of the transactions 
balance = initial_balance + amounts.sum()
```